# What is the simplest way to export a bezier curve created in Blender to a text file?

Tags: blender, collada, beziers, export

I have created a `bezier curve` in `Blender`.

[image]

I'd like to export this curve to a `text file`. What I need is :

Control point + handles, three points in total.

Example :

```
{{ 2.3333,4.3942, 55.333 }, { 0.3234, 2.4234, 4.0332 }, { 2.534, 6.S234, 12.0332 }}
```

I have tried to export the scene in `Collada` format but it doesn't seems to include curves information.

What is the easiest / simplest way to export this curve to some readable text file format ?

Comment: can anyone say why doesn't the exported Collada file include curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [scripts available](http://www.macouno.com/2010/03/17/bezier-export/) that do this. Though they may be a bit out of date. Perhaps not the simplest method, but you can write your own python script to export them. Using Blender scripting you can [enumerate the objects](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Extensions/Python/BSoD/Objects_And_Their_Properties) in the scene and then enumerate through all the curves of a particular bezier curve.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the scripts i have found (including the one you suggest) are for old version of Blender (2.4?). It seems they changed almost all the api since recent 2.6 versions (the one i use). Even documentation for 2.6 still do not exists : http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Extensions/Python/BSoD/Objects_And_Their_Properties. Do you recommand sticking with old version ? I was expecting some Blender script guru to show me a simple script example to start with. eg: how to loop on control points of a curve.

Comment: Here's blender python api for 2.66a: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_66a_release/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import bpy
myCurve = bpy.data.curves[0] # here your curve
spline= myCurve.splines[0] # maybe you need a loop if more than 1 spline

print("\n======================")
for x in range(len(spline.bezier_points)):
    print("Point " + str(x)
        ,spline.bezier_points[x].co
        ,spline.bezier_points[x].handle_left
        ,spline.bezier_points[x].handle_right)
```

Comment: How would one integrate this Python script into Blender in order to utilize it?  This seems like the start of a good answer but it could be expanded upon.

Comment: blender incorporates and depends on python to run. You can paste this code into a text window and run it as a script. The top of the blender window most likely lists default as the current layout, change that to scripting to see a layout with 3dview, text and python console visible.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is revelant code :

```
ob = bpy.context.object # active object 

# iterate over points of the curve's first spline 
file = open('foo.txt', 'w')     
for p in ob.data.splines.active.bezier_points: 
    file.write("%.3f, %.3f, %.3f" % p.co.x, p.co.y, p.co.z) 
    file.write("%.3f, %.3f, %.3f" % p.handle_left.x, p.handle_left.y, p.handle_left.z) 
    file.write("%.3f, %.3f, %.3f" % p.handle_right.x, p.handle_right.y,p.handle_right.z) 
fclose(f)
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. You should edit the original question to add any extra info.